# How can I make a tags ranking in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ranking

I'm trying to create a script for personal purposes. I'm analyzing lists of blog posts, fetching their tags and I need to obtain a tags ranking.

```
post1_tags: ['chocolate','drink','sweet','food','cocoa']
post2_tags: ['cake','sacher','apricot','chocolate','cream']
post3_tags: ['cheesecake','cake','baking','sour cream','new york']
```

I managed to create an array of the kind tags['chocolate'=2,'drink'=1,'sweet'=1 etc ] but I'm not able to go on. Looks like is not possible to sort an array like that. I tried in many ways, searched a lot into stackoverflow but I was able just to sort by tag name. The purpose of the script is in fact to know the most popular tags in a given set of posts.

```
var tags = ["muffin","tin","cupcake","cupcake","holders","cupcake","quality","blog","muffin"];

var tags_rank = {};
$.each(tags, function(index,value){
if (!tags_rank[value]) {
    tags_rank[value] = 1;
}
else {
    tags_rank[value]++;
}
});
```

The array (tags_rank) I get is:

```
Object { muffin=2, tin=1, cupcake=3, ...}
```

I'm not able to sort it out.
I need the script to show a ranking of the top tags used like:

Cupcake: 3
Muffin: 2
Milk: 2
Chocolate: 1

Thank you in advance.
S.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/1032493

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javacript solution:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn5JW/)

```
var tags = ["muffin","tin","cupcake","cupcake","holders","cupcake","quality","blog","muffin"];

var ranking = [];
var found;

for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
    found = false;

    for(var x=0; x<ranking.length; x++) {
        if(ranking[x].tag == tags[i]) {
            found = true;
            ranking[x].count++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found) {
        ranking[x] = { tag : tags[i], count : 1 };   
    }
}

ranking.sort(function(a, b){
  if (a.count < b.count)
     return 1;
  if (a.count > b.count)
    return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

The result is an array `ranking` which looks like:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "cupcake",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "tag": "muffin",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "tag": "tin",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "tag": "holders",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "tag": "quality",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "tag": "blog",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```